# how to stream bitmap data over a socket in cpp?

Tags: c++

I am working on a remote administration project in cpp that will stream graphic data- in bitmap object- over winsock. The winsock send and rcv function use only buffers of data type char*. How can I stream data from bitmap object over a socket?

Answer (score 0):

Cast your buffers to char * and pass the size of the buffer in bytes as the length. Note that send() can only deal with whole bytes.

Comment: Recommend recommending that the asker establish some sort of communication protocol so they can easily tell when one bitmap ends and another bitmap begins.